# Find control in application page?

Tags: 2010, development

This line returns null

```
Button BtnCopy = Page.FindControl("BtnCopy") as Button;
```

but the control is there in the markup.

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnCopy" runat="server"
```

the entire method is called in the application page load.  Its a modal dialog from acustom action

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("CopyRequestToAnotherYear", "Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)", "BEGIN");
            string messageSource = Request.Url.ToString();
            string listId = Request.QueryString["ListID"];
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            string state = Request.GetQueryStringValue(SponsoringCommon.Constants.QUERYSTRINGPARAMETER_STATE_NAME);
            string statusMessage = Request.GetQueryStringValue(SponsoringCommon.Constants.QUERYSTRINGPARAMETER_MESSAGE_NAME);
            LoadNextYears(int.Parse(SPContext.Current.Web.Name));
        }


private void LoadNextYears(int currentYear)
    {
        DdlYear.Items.Clear();
        bool yearsExist = false;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;                    
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currentWeb.Url))
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                {
                    if (web.WebTemplate == "NLSPONSORINGYEAR" &&  int.Parse(web.Title) > currentYear)
                    {
                        DdlYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(web.Name, web.Name));
                        yearsExist = true;
                    }
                }
            }                
        });

        Button BtnCopy = Page.FindControl("BtnCopy") as Button;
        if (yearsExist)
            BtnCopy.Enabled = true;
        else
            BtnCopy.Enabled = false;
    }




<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Year: </td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DdlYear" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="BtnCopy" runat="server" OnClick="BtnCopy_Click" Text="<%$Resources:SPNLSponsoring, btnCopyToAnotherYear%>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Exactly in which event you are doing Page.FindControl, may be the control is not rendered yet, are you using some other event than CreateChildControl

Comment: in the page load, pls see the updated question with more info

Comment: if it helps, the .cs class inherits from : LayoutsPageBase

Comment: FindControl only works for current container, so make sure Button is directly under page, can you post the front end also?

Comment: its inside a content placeholder, I pasted the frontend, not all, but does it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
ContentPlaceHolder content = Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain") as ContentPlaceHolder;
Button BtnCopy = content.FindControl("BtnCopy") as Button;
```

Have not tested the code, but this is the only solution that came into my mind

Answer (score 0):

My question is why you can grab the DropDownList without `FindControl`, but not the button. They are at the same level and both asp controls.

```
   `DdlYear.Items.Clear();`
```

Try using the BtnCopy instance.

Comment: the page is in the sharepoint solution, but the code behind is in a different class library., I am not actually grabing the dropdownlist, its an instance of the same class, I guess if I do findcontrol it wont work either